# Best Practice: include( or <script src="

Tags: php, javascript, css, include

I have minified my javascript and my css.

Now, Which is better?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?
  $r = file_get_contents('min.js');
  if($r) echo $r;
?>
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="min.js"></script>
```

Same question for CSS.

If the answer is 'sometimes because browsers fetch files simultaneously?'  Which browsers, and what are examples of the times in either scenario.

Comment: This is tagged incorectly 'http'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="min.js"></script>
```

...is better, as the user's browser can cache the file.

Adding a parameter to the `src` such as the file's last modified timestamp is even better, as the user's browser will cache the file but will always retrieve the most up to date version when the file is modified.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="min.js?version=20081007134916"></script>
```

Comment: With 20-60% of users having an empty cache, is it better to have less HTTP requests or cached results?

Comment: Aren't browsers supposed to get that information from the HTTP headers?

Comment: Issac - key phrase; "supposed to".  Quite often the caching on js files is very aggressive

Comment: Additionally, this is better practice because it's keeping the behavior logic out of the presentation logic. If it's not HTML, then it doesn't belong in a .html file.

Comment: Tom - that's all nice and fine when you're programming, but your build HTML files are made to be read by a browser, not a programmer.  If you're making things to be read and interpreted by people, you'd never minify it in the first place.

Comment: @Isaac
You're absolutely right - I mis-read the question. My fault on that.

Comment: "With 20-60% of users having an empty cache" - that means 40-80% *don't* have an empty cache.

Comment: You shouldn't use querystring revisioning.  Some caching proxies will never cache requests with a querystring:  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

Answer (score 6):

It's better the most times to include javascript and css files because that way the browser is able to cache the javascript/css file. That way the file is only loaded once by the browser even if you include the file in several other pages.

But this is only true if you set an appropriate expires and/or cache-control header for javascript and css files via php or Apache mod_expires.

Based on the recommondation by the Yahoo Exceptional Performance there is only one exception:

> The only exception where inlining is preferable is with home pages, such as Yahoo!'s front page and My Yahoo!. Home pages that have few (perhaps only one) page view per session may find that inlining JavaScript and CSS results in faster end-user response times.

I higly suggest you try out the Addon "YSlow for Firebug". It answers alot of questions about caching and browser/client -performance.

See also:

[Apache mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_expires.html)

[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the browser can download AT MOST two files in parallel from the same domain (that's the default on the modern browsers - i'm certain about IE6 and IE7, not sure about others). This means that if your page references 20 tiny javascript files, many will get downloaded sequentially.

To add to what was already said: remember that if you combine/minify your javascript files, it's better to merge them all into one - the compression will work better. Additionally, even if you don't minify your files, remember to turn on GZIP in your web server config; then, if you combine all your JS files into one and include that file as , the GZIP compression will work best (because compressing two JS files together produces better results than compressing each separately).

If you're looking for a good JS minification utility, try JS Packer (http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

Comment: As long as you're gzipping, Packer is counterproductive.  JSMin, YUI Compressor, and Packer all have very nearly the same gzipped footprint, but Packer introduces a client-side delay as it's eval()'d.  Packer is great if you need obfuscation though.